# semantic-ui dist folder - Deployment without npm and/or gulp

Tags: semantic-ui

I have a dist folder inside semantic-ui zip file that I downloaded (version 1.8.1 to be precise)

Is this folder the only thing i need to deploy my Web Application as far as semantic-ui related files are concerned?

Would including semantic.js and semantic.css be enough for my web application?

I am asking this question as I want to eliminate the need of installing npm and gulp on my target machines and would just like to copy over the css and js files that are needed by the application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Including semantic.min.js, jquery, and semantic.min.css will should be enough for the start since the semantic.min.js contains all the modules you'd need. You will find these files in 'dist' folder.

Comment: Is it possible to include a site theme as well using this approach? What files should i include for that?

Comment: I'm not sure about that since I didn't work with the themes semantic-ui provides. The documentation provides much more information about that. You can follow that http://learnsemantic.com/themes/overview.html